# Kafka Connect JDBC sink - write Avro field into PG JSONB

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to build a pipeline where Avro data is written into a Postgres DB. Everything works fine with simple schemas and the AvroConverter for the values. However, I would like to have a nested field written into a JSONB column. There are a couple of problems with this. First, it seems that the Connect plugin does not support STRUCT data. Second, the plugin cannot write directly into the JSONB column.

The second problem should be avoided by adding a cast in PG, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/46#issuecomment-625638734). The first problem is proving more diffult. I have tried different [transformations](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/cast.html) but have not been able to get the Connect plugin to interpret one complex field as a string. The schema in questions looks something like this (in practice there would be more fields on the first level besides the timestamp):

```
{
  "namespace": "test.schema",
  "name": "nested_message",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "nested_field",
      "type": {
        "name": "nested_field_record",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "prop",
            "type": "float",
            "doc": "Some property"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The message is written in Kafka as

```
{"timestamp":1599493668741396400,"nested_field":{"name":"myname","prop":377.93887}}
```

In order to write the contents of `nested_field` into a single DB column, I would like to interpret this *entire* field as a string. Is this possible? I have tried the [cast](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/cast.html) transformation, but this only supports prmitive Avro types. Something along the lines of [HoistField](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/hoistfield.html) could work, but I don't see a way to limit this to a single field. Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

A completely different approach would be to use two connect plugins and UPSERT into the table. One plugin would use the AvroConverter for all fields save the nested one, while the second plugin uses the StringConverter for the nested field. This feels wrong in all kinds of ways though.